# Exclude rows if the id match

Tags: mysql

How can I exclude row with same id. I have a table of members activity, where member id is repeated many times in the table. I want to get all member id but in this case if I select member id I will get all ids and I want one id only one time without repetition.

```
ID | OwnerID | Date               | GroupID
1    1        2012-04-23 19:25:04  1
2    1        2012-04-23 19:26:55  1
3    2        2012-04-23 19:26:56  1
4    1        2012-04-23 19:26:58  1
5    2        2012-04-23 19:27:14  1
```

Here if I select the OwnerID I will get 1 three times and I want it to return only 1 time. Its like I just want to have a list of user who is in this table and don't want how many times he/she comes up in this table. I hope it makes sense.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, for this question a little more search on google explained me DISTINCT. But thanks for your answers...:)

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT DISTINCT(yourMemberIDField) FROM someWonkyTable`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT (OwnerID) FROM Table`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
select OwnerID
from table_name
group by OwnerID
```

This will group all the rows by OwnerID making sure only one of each is returned.